# What cannot be developed for Sharepoint Server 2010 in 32-bit workstation? and in 64-bit workstation?

Tags: 2010, development, infopath, administration

Before, I was developing remotely on Microsoft Sharepoint Server 2010 machine (Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter and all servers 64-bit) accessing it over internet through RDP from **Windows XP SP3 32-bit**. So, I developed remotely in 64-bit computer, had no restrictions or even necessity to think what could be unavailable to me.

Recently I started to work with Office 365 (Sharepoint Online), Plan E3, from my home Windows XP SP3 32-bit (x86) using Sharepoint Designer 2010 32-bit and Infopath Developer 2010 32-bit, again from 32-bit computer. I.e. I develop locally in 32-bit environment deploying to Sharepoint Server 2010.

How far can I develop locally in 32-bit machine, i.e. without buying me 64-bit computer or, in other words, what cannot I develop in 32-bit workstation?
What are possible pitfalls?

What cannot I develop in 64-bit workstation or, in other words, which development scenarios require coding on 64-bit servers?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not support running on 32bit machines so you will not be able to run a local version of SharePoint.

Using SharePoint online you would normally have the development choice of using Sandbox solutions which can be built in Visual Studio 2010.  This development would require a local development environment running both SharePoint and VS 2010 on a 64bit computer.

SharePoint Designer and InfoPath as clients will be fine when connecting to O365.